# child div overlapping, not respecting parent div width

Tags: html, css

I'm building a prototype for a Web Application and I have a problem with div overlapping.

I have a div called `#menu`, with `width: 15%;`, and inside of it, I have a child div called `#list` with `width: 100%;`.

[image]

At a first glance, it seems that the **child** div is not respecting the limit of the **parent** div, remembering that the **child** div has `position: absolute;`.

There a some questions about this subject, but I didn't found any question that suits to my case. Some of the questions talks about applying `clear: both` on all divs or to apply `display: inline-block;`, but nothing worked.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<html>

  <head>

    <title> PROTOTYPE - opcion.html</title>

    <style type="text/css">

      body {
        margin: 0;
      }

      #menu {
        display: block;
        height: 100%;
        width: 15%;
        background-color:#ff0000;
      }

      #list {
        width: 100%;
        top: 180px;
        position: absolute;
      }

      ul {
        background-color: aqua;
        display: block;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
      }

      li {
        margin: auto;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 10px 0px 10px 10px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.6);
      }

      li a {
        color: #ffffff;
        font-size: 25px;
        font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
        text-decoration: none;
      }

    </style>

  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="menu">
      <div id="list">
        <ul>
          <li> <a href="#">Customers</a> </li>
          <li> <a href="#">Students</a> </li>
          <li> <a href="#">Teachers</a> </li>
          <li> <a href="#">Android App</a> </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: just add position:relative to #menu. your absolute container will respect the parent's attribute that has a position relative. 'clear ' is required only when you float an element.

Comment: Thanks! Would you please write it as an answer so I can upvote an accept your recommendation?

Comment: sure thanks. I am adding some reference links too, which will be useful

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate that Karthick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add position:relative to #menu. your absolute container will respect the parent's attribute that has a position relative.

To learn more about position
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/

'clear ' is required only when you float an element.

Answer (score 1):

Nice title. The parent div needs to have a position of relative in order to have the absolute positioned element be contained inside it. Add this code to your style:

```
#menu {
position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
<html>
```

```
<title> PROTOTYPE - opcion.html</title>

<style type="text/css">
    body {
        margin: 0;
    }

    #menu {
        display: block;
        height: 100%;
        width: 15%;
        background-color: #ff0000;
    }

    #list {
        width: inherit;
        top: 180px;
        position: absolute;
    }

    ul {
        background-color: aqua;
        display: block;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
    }

    li {
        margin: auto;
        width: inherit;
        padding: 10px 0px 10px 10px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.6);
    }

        li a {
            color: #ffffff;
            font-size: 25px;
            font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
</style>
```

```
<div id="menu">
    <div id="list">
        <ul>
            <li> <a href="#">Customers</a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#">Students</a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#">Teachers</a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#">Android App</a> </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

in list css and li css use:

```
width: inherit;
```